# I have a vector of Base and Derived Class Objects, but I can't access data members inherited by derived objects that are stored in the vector

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector

Bear with me, I'm relatively new at C++.

Here is my project.  I want to essentially create a simple game of chess.

I've got a base class gamePiece, which I'm thinking will eventually become an abstract class ( but right now it isn't)

The base class gamePiece has a bunch of data members in it:  colorOfPiece, rankOfPiece, fileOfPiece, etc.  It also has a function, void displayPieceInfo()  which simply displays all of these values on the console via cout.

I am planning on having a number of derived classes from this one.  Right now I have a "rook" subclass.

I want to add various types of pieces in a single vector, so I can later traverse it with an iterator.

Here is the problem I am running into.

```
vector<gamePiece> vectorOfAllGamePieces;
vector<gamePiece>::iterator itGamePieces;
```

I push_back a Rook into the vector as the first element.  All the constructors look like they are running fine, initializing the variables.  Yet when I try to run the display function on the first element, the strings are empty/unitialized.

```
itGamePieces=vectorOfAllGamePieces.begin();
itGamePieces->displayPieceInfo();
```

If I were to push in a generic gamePiece into the vector instead, everything would display properly.

Am I allowed to even have a vector like this with mixed types of objects -- for example, an object of a derived class, an object of the parent class, an object of a second class derived from the same parent

And if so, why do you suppose the values of the data members aren't showing up properly, even after I have set them in the constructor?

Comment: The joys of slicing. You don't, in fact, have a vector of both base and derived. That vector only contains bases.

Answer (score 3):

Not really, because of slicing. When you add a derived object to a `vector<gamePiece>`, it gets sliced and a `gamePiece` object is actually added to the vector.

You'll need to use a vector of (smart) pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is like this, `Rook` **is a** `GamePiece`. But You Cannot Store a Rook in a place for GamePieces. You can only **cast** a `Pointer to Rook` to a `Pointer to GamePiece`. So your vector must be saving **NOT** `GamePieces` but `GamePiece *` (Pointers to GamePieces).

```
std::vector<GamePiece *> vectorOfAllGamePieces;
```

But this could give you trouble in memory management. Another way is to store `Handles` without using pointers. ( a handle is something like a pointer to a pointer ). Or of course you can use smart pointers.

A quick hack will be ( this is a "hack" which is "evil" in the eyes of some people ),

```
std::vector<Rook> allRooks;
std::vector<Pawns> allPawns;
.....
std::vector<Queen> allQueens;
King theKing;

std::vector<GamePiece *> allPieces;
```

The `allPieces` will contain pointers to objects in the other vectors.
I think this is kind of OK when you know exactly all the types of pieces ( i guess this is chess ).